# SQLExpress error: Invalid object name 'Cats'

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have installed the same database and scripts on several Windows Server 2008 machines, and today I get this odd error...

```
Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers error '80040e37'

[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'Cats'.
```

It works perfectly on every other server, but not this one. What could this be about?

Comment: have your tried [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/197463)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to spajce's tip this problem has been resolved. For some reason the DSN had not nominated the database to access.

To change the default database for the DSN to the correct database, do the following:

1. Open Control Panel.
2. Double-click the ODBC Control Panel extension to launch the ODBC Administrator.
3. Click the System DSN tab in the ODBC Administrator.
4. Select the System datasource that is mapped to the Commerce Server database.
5. Click the Configure button to launch the SQL Server DSN Configuration wizard.
6. Click the Next button twice.
7. On the third page, click the "Change the default database" checkbox.
8. Click the Next button twice, click Finish, and then click OK.